# How does the Linux C++ compiler (and linker) decide where to put typeinfo?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, linker, rtti

I have a class defined in one h file and implemented in a cpp that is part of one lib (we'll call it libdef).

I have two other libs that have cpp files that include this h file. One of them does dynamic_cast() to this class (we'll call it libdyn) and the other does new for this class (we'll call it libnew).

It seems that in one of these libs there's typeinfo for the type but not in the other:

```
user@machine> ld --cref libdef.so | grep -E "typeinfo for MyClass"
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
typeinfo for MyClass libdef.so

user@machine> ld --cref libnew.so | grep -E "typeinfo for MyClass"
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
typeinfo for MyClass libdef.so

user@machine> ld --cref libdyn.so | grep -E "typeinfo for MyClass"
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
typeinfo for MyClass libdyn.so
```

As you can see both libdef and libnew use the typeinfo from libdef, but libdyn uses its own typeinfo. Why is that? How does the compiler/linker decide whether to put the typeinfo in one lib or reference it from the other?

I should note that both libnew and libdyn are built with -llibdef.

```
user@machine> icpc -V
Intel(R) C++ Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 12.0.0.084 Build 20101006
Copyright (C) 1985-2010 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

user@machine> ld -V
GNU ld version 2.17.50.0.6-14.el5 20061020
Supported emulations:
 elf_x86_64
 elf_i386
 i386linux
```

After some checks I did, it depends on whether the cpp files of the lib "see" a virtual method definition or not.

This code will not result in the typeinfo symbol being in the library:

```
class SomeClass { public: SomeClass(); virtual void func(); };
```

This code will produce a typeinfo symbol in the library:

```
class SomeClass { public: SomeClass() {} virtual void func() {} };
```

When present, the typeinfo symbol will have vague linkage.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that there's only one typeinfo object per type... the standard does not guarantee this, it only guarantees that if there are multiple, they will compare equal.

Comment: @Ben The thing is that if there are multiple, they do not compare equal in Linux (because of the use of address comparison). This is not suppose to happen if you use libs only as gcc tells you to but we still have a problem with it and I'm trying to find some work around for our product.

Comment: by "compare equal", I do not mean address comparison.  I mean `operator=` which is defined for objects of type `typeinfo`.  That's the only mechanism the standard guarantees will work for comparing typeinfo instances.

Comment: @Ben I don't know if the address comparison is implemented in operator== or not, but I do know (well, read it somewhere) that the dynamic_cast() uses address comparison on Linux to determine type equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

G++ probably defines the typeinfo for the class as a weak
symbol, in every object file that needs it.  One of the object
files in `libdef` needs it, because it's part of the `vtable`
installed by the constructor.  And one of the object files in
`libdyn` needs it, because of the `dynamic_cast`.  If all
`libnew` does is a new, however, it likely wouldn't need it
(unless the constructor is inline).  At any rate, if it really
is a weak symbol, only one of the definitions will be
incorporated into the final so or executable; which one is
unspecified (but I suspect that it is the first one the linker
encounters—which corresponds to what you're seeing).

None of which matters most of the time.  (The exception is if
you're calling `dlopen` with `RTLD_LOCAL`; do this, and
`dynamic_cast` is likely to fail if it executed in an `.so`
other than the one with the object's constructor.)

Comment: You are probably right, but isn't there a way to make it reference it from another lib and not use its own typeinfo?

Comment: Not that I know of.  The whole raison d'etre behind weak references is that *every* use provokes a definition (in the `.o` file), and that the linker chooses one---for all intents an purposes, at random.  One of the motivations of the ODR is to allow this implementation technique.  If anything in your class definitions would cause the typeinfo to be different, then you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, this depends on the C++ implementation.  But [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html) is a description of how g++ does it.

Briefly, when possible, g++ defines the class vtable and type_info in the translation unit which defines the first non-inline virtual member of the class.

Comment: I wonder if the description in the link is up-to-date.  (I know that the URL says 4.6, but it's possible that the text itself is older, and hasn't been updated.)  There's no mention of weak binding, and this is the technique g++ uses for things like template instantiations.  (If you follow the link to templates on that page, it leads to a page talking about Borland model and CFront model.  A very definite sign that it isn't up to date.)

Comment: @James: From what I can tell using nm, recent versions of g++ use both weak binding and "key method" techniques for vtables and type_info.

Comment: @ashepler I'm not sure what they do for typeinfo---my comments about weak binding there were just a guess.  I do know that weak symbols are used in template instantiations, however, and it seems reasonable that they are also used here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be an implementation detail of compiler.

Usually(since virtual table itself is a implementation detail), the `virtual table` stores a pointer to the `type info` and I think where the typeinfo is stored is implementation detail of compiler. Most probably it stores the `typeinfo` in the `so` which declares the class.

Comment: The declaration is in a header which is included in translation units in all 3 libs. If all of them had the typeinfo in them, it would make sense, but what confuses me is that one has it and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the implementation details of your compiler and linker, but perhaps it's smart enough not to include the typeinfo where it isn't needed?